# Synaptics Clickpad not recognized

Tags: windows-8.1, synaptics-touchpad

After a complete disk wipe on my Acer V5-573G I installed Windows 8.1 and the synaptics drivers for the touchpad, version 17.0.6.17 which I downloaded from the Acer Website.

The driver install did not show any errors, but the touchpad is not recognized as a **Synaptics Clickpad V8.1** (as it was before the reinstall).

Under Mouse Properties > Device Settings it is shown as **Standard pointing device on PS/2 port**.

In device manager it is shown as **Synaptics PS/2 Port Touchpad**.

I also tried to install the latest driver from the Synaptics website which shows version 17.0.19, but the installation fails with a generic "Installation failed" message.

My problem is now that I cannot access the advanced settings for the touchpad. How can I fix this?

Comment: The current driver from Synaptics shows 17.0.19; did you try that one. Did you d/l from Acer or Synaptics?

Comment: Thx for your comment, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the hardware ID in device manager, I realized this model had the **Elan Touchpad**, instead of the Synaptics one. The Elan drivers installed without any problem.

Comment: If you want to enable advanced Synaptics like features on your Elan touchpad, you might want to [check out my answer](http://superuser.com/a/799165/167187)