# How to configure swipe gestures on Win 8.1 for a Dell Venue 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, drivers, dell-venue

I would like to change the touch swipe gestures for a Dell Venue 8 Pro. Similar to this quesiton: [Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop) however the hardware does not support the synaptic driver. It is some windows internal device (no driver listed under the HID touch screen device).

I know there must be a way to do it. I could write my own software to record and monitor each mouse movement, but I'd really rather just hook the existing swipe gesture which occurs at the driver level.

Ultimately I want to connect this to a progam called Dexpot which can be configured to work with any keystroke. This will allow application switching (something which is currently impossible with Win 8 (I'm not using metro apps and have pretty much uninstalled most of the metro charm garbage). I'm trying to switch between apps which would normally be found in the taskbar; however hidden by the on-screen keyboard.

I did try to contact Dell, I doubt they understood what my request was, so until they get 1,000 similar calls I think updating the driver officially is a dead-end.

Comment: This only works for laptops with a touchpad. What you have is a tablet PC with a touch screen so there are no touchpad settings to configure/hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can however, [customize gestures for tablet PCs](http://microsoft-news.com/customize-your-very-own-touchscreen-gestures-on-your-windows-8-device-using-touchme-gesture-studio-its-awesome/) using an app like [TouchMe Gesture Studio](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/touchme-gesture-studio/740d3578-ddb4-4f74-b489-5a3782cb7607)

Comment: I've come across this. This software does not create gestures rather it creates file file that would serve as the input file to some other paid program. The next problem is that this is some metro [cr]app. The next problem is that it is selling to user what they would already get for free from a Synaptic driver update (if dell had not have prevented that driver). The next problem is that it is implemented at the software level not driver level (so I might as well write it myself). But I do appreciate you looking into it!

Comment: If you're looking for a free solution with scripting capabilities, try [StrokePlus](http://www.strokesplus.com/). It's not implemented at the driver level, but I guess it'll get the job done. The website says you require a pen (stylus) to be able to use it.

Comment: It's not so much about it being free as being a right vs wrong issue. Dell/Microsoft have prevented users from configuration of the OS so that they could then sell (and track user through forced registration). I've been trying hard to embrace this OS but I don't see it happening. Not when I can do this all seamlessly in linux. Not being able to configure a simple thing like this may be the last straw...

Comment: This is probably not related to your question, but while researching a solution, I learnt how to modify my touchpad driver to include a lot more gestures and enable functions that were previously deactivated. I don't think they'll be of much use to you since you don't have a touchpad on your tablet PC. However, you might want to take a look at my answer (I'll be posting one in a few hours) and see if you can come up with something similar. Here's my question: http://superuser.com/q/700348