# ELAN Touchpad Reverse Scrolling

Tags: touchpad

I have a Samsung Chronos 7 laptop that has reverse scrolling enabled and I can't seem to figure out how to switch it to natural scrolling. I tried to do it through through the registry with no luck. I found a forum that told me to use the ETDSimpleUI.exe instead of the Win8 one, same UI screen. At this point and I lost and it is kind of annoying.

Comment: Registry hacks are reverted as soon as you make them. You need to edit the driver INF. The disadvantage is that you need to enable `TESTSIGNING` so you can install the modded drivers, but ELAN has a host of useful features that's disabled by default that you can enable/tweak. [My answer](http://superuser.com/a/799165/167187) might help you with this.

Answer (score 7):

Edit Windows Registry to do this.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to open Run.
2. Type `regedit` in Run and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
3. In the Registry Editor, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad`.
4. Two keys under this directory are `SC_Reverse_Enable` and `SC_Reverse_ShowItem`. Double click on them and change their values from 0 to 1.

Making `SC_Reverse_Enable` 1 inverts the scroll direction, whereas making `SC_Reverse_ShowItem` 1 shows this option in the GUI menu under Control Panel -> Mouse -> ELAN -> Options.

Source: https://rog.asus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-34600.html

Comment: Excellent! I really wonder why the option is even hidden in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

A friend just had the same problem and we both have ELAN touchpads. I wanted to show him how it's done but the checkbox was missing on his PC and exists on my pc. You should be able to just install the newest ELAN touchpad software and then do it as shown here:
[image: tutorial elan disable invert scrolling]

Answer (score 1):

This is the key that you need to change.

Open Registry Editor, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPadDisplay`, find key `ScrollOnlyV_Display` and change the value to `1`.