# How can I programmatically alter Elan touchpad scroll direction?

Tags: windows-11, touchpad, scrolling

### **The Problem & Objective**

Recent WinOS updates appear to be wiping touchpad configuration settings (as applied through the frontend `Settings` user space); particularly, having the touchpad scroll direction **inverted** (apparently this is the default behavior, so perhaps "inverted" isn't the best vernacular to use here) is *really* bothersome.  As such, the primary focal point of this question is this: how can I programmatically alter the touchpad's default scroll direction (or otherwise automatically apply the desired setting on boot/startup/login)?

### **Hardware Specs**

**Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3-15IHU6 - Type 82K1**

**OS**  Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
**Version** 10.0.22635 Build 22635
**OS Manufacturer** Microsoft Corporation
**System Manufacturer** LENOVO
**System Model**    82K1
**System Type** x64-based PC
**System SKU**  LENOVO_MT_82K1_BU_idea_FM_IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IHU6
**Processor**   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11370H @ 3.30GHz, 3302 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
**BIOS Version/Date**   LENOVO H4CN32WW(V2.01), 7/13/2023
**SMBIOS Version**  3.3
**Embedded Controller Version** 2.32
**BIOS Mode**   UEFI
**BaseBoard Manufacturer**  LENOVO
**BaseBoard Product**   LNVNB161216
**BaseBoard Version**   SDK0T76463 WIN
**Platform Role**   Mobile
**PCR7 Configuration**  Binding Not Possible

**Hardware ID's**
HID\VEN_ELAN&DEV_0001&Col03
HID\ELAN0001&Col03
HID*ELAN0001&Col03
HID\VID_04F3&UP:000D_U:0005
HID_DEVICE_UP:000D_U:0005
HID_DEVICE

### **What I've Done So Far**

- I've located the device in `Device Manager` and grabbed the hardware ID:
  `HID\VEN_ELAN&DEV_0001&Col03`
- I've determined that there is no such control through group policy editor, nor OEM software/utility/driver available from this specific product's support page.
- I've found a related post (see below) that indicates a location for a key in `regedit` that should control this device parameter, but that path doesn't exist in my registry (likely for a different product).
- I've *believe* I've located the registry directory for the touchpad in question:
  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\HID\ELAN0001&Col03\5&1aa11294&0&0002`
- Here is a screenshot of the current registry key directory (note that `Property` is inaccessible and `Parameters` is empty other than `(Default)`):
  [image: Screenshot1]

### **Related Posts**

[ELAN Touchpad Reverse Scrolling](https://superuser.com/questions/808271/elan-touchpad-reverse-scrolling)

Comment: Did you get ELAN to work in the correct direction?

Comment: So here's the funny thing: I did **not** manage to fix the issue, but while I was using the notebook I had a BSOD with an error code stating "a page fault occurred in...non-paged space" or something along those lines (can't recall exactly).  Upon rebooting after that BSOD, the issue had spontaneously fixed itself.  I am part of the beta flight channel, so my guess is that something in the most recent updates broke something, and when it caused the BSOD whatever was broken got rolled back, which then fixed the issue with the touchpad?  I haven't updated since, and I'm in no hurry to do so.